# Increment in the renewal process is not icrement but the total TTL?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I've been playing with Vault's API. I was trying to renew token at the /auth/token/renew-self endpoint however it seems that documented parameter does not work.

https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/token/index.html:

```
increment (string: "") - An optional requested lease increment can be provided. This increment may be ignored.
```

When I POST there

```
{"increment": "1d"}
```

I'm getting:

```
{"errors":["1 error occurred:\n\t* error converting input 1d for field \"increment\": strconv.ParseInt: parsing \"1d\": invalid syntax\n\n"]}
```

So I've changed 1d to 86400 but suddenly token's TTL has dropped to ~86400 - provided increment.

**Could someone confirm this behavior?**

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documentation issue, can definitely be more clear.

```
The renew api actually resets the the "ttl" to 86400.
```

That is the reason the documentation mentions that the value of "increment" may be ignored. In practice it makes sense to have "ttl" set to a default value(86400), everytime when renewal api is invoked as there will be no need to remember the custom ttl configured. Hope this helps.